# Npm install not working for ionic 3, npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3, npm-install

I have issues for days. Now i try to create an ionic v3 app and every time it stops at line below.

```
√ Preparing directory .\firstProject - done!
√ Downloading and extracting blank starter - done!
? Integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes

ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet
[INFO] Downloading integration cordova
[INFO] Copying integrations files to project
[OK] Integration cordova added!

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

 *   IONIC  DEVAPP   *
Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app

Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
LiveReload for instant style and JS updates
–> Install DevApp: https://ionicframework.com/docs/pro/devapp/ <–

────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

npm i
npm WARN deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer
npm ERR! code Z_BUF_ERROR
npm ERR! errno -5
npm ERR! zlib: unexpected end of file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-09-01T04_12_23_741Z-debug.log
[ERROR] Non-zero exit from subprocess.
```

I looked up this

> deprecated browserslist@2.11.3: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading
>   Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools

but couldn't find anything that works.

Comment: NPM is currently having issues. Maybe you should keep an eye on https://status.npmjs.org/ and wait until they have fixed their DNS issues.

Comment: I would recommend to use yarn if possible, as it is having better dependency management compared to npm.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple, just clear NPM cache

```
npm cache clear --force
```

and then, try again

```
npm install
```